# Ping WCF Data Service or WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, performance, wcf, wcf-data-services

I investigated a bad thing, suppose we have a data service and we want to call it in consumer side such as:

```
 Uri dataManURI = new Uri("http://localhost:2040/DTService.svc/rest");
 DataServiceContext dataServiceContext = new DataServiceContext(dataManURI);
 var all = from ex in dataServiceContext.CreateQuery<ExternalPath_DTO>("ExternalPaths")
                                                      select ex;
```

after **long time** I will get:

> Failed to load external path!, EXP:System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceTransportException: The operation has timed out ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.GetResponseHelper(ODataRequestMessageWrapper request, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException)
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()

or WCF service:

```
 AuthClient ac = new AuthClient("authEndPoint", Token);
 ac.RemoveUser(new RemoveUser_DTO_IN() { UserId = uidToDel });
```

so if the service is not available it is take long time to catch the exception  I think if I set `receivetimeout` to `00:01:00` it will take 1 minute to know operation get time out.

in the other side UI **be frozen** until response (in my case 1 minute to get fail response).

Is these solution are useful if yes but how?

**1-** Define a simple operation such as `Ping()` and call it before any main operation ?

```
   AuthClient ac = new AuthClient("authEndPoint", Token);
   var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
   var ping = Task.Run(() =>
   {
      ac.Ping();
   });
   try
   { 
     if (!ping.Wait(ac.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout))
       {
          //Timeout on Ping for end point
           watch.Stop(); 
           return;
        }
   }
   catch (Exception exp)
    {
      watch.Stop(); 
      return;
    }
```

My expect is to get response within 3 seconds (open time out), in my opinion if a `Ping()` won't reply in 3 seconds then that service is not available.

**2-** telnet the service ?

**Solution 1:** I think solution 1 is not proper without task programming and `!ping.Wait(ac.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout)`, because of my above explanation if service is not available then it will take 1 minute(end point receive time) to say operation get timed out.

**Solution 2:** how, real example?

Is there any other mechanism to know very fast that service is available or not ?

any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: _"Waking up the service"_ or _"pinging the service to see if it's alive"_  are XY problems. Your actual problem is _"When calling the service, the client gets a timeout"_, so fix **that** problem. Investigate why the service is taking a long time to respond. It may very well be up and running and happily respond when you ping it, but the operation you intend to execute will still time out, because it hits a badly performing database or whatever.

Comment: I know it may happened because of networking problem not code performance or anything related to my code...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to [Warm-up your IIS pool initialization](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization)?

> A common problem faced by website administrators is the need to perform initialization tasks and "warm up" tasks for a web application. Larger and more complex web applications may need to perform lengthy startup processing, prime in-memory caches, generate content, etc... prior to serving the first HTTP request.
>
> The IIS 8.0 Application Initialization feature enables website administrators to configure IIS 8.0 to proactively perform initialization tasks for one or more web applications.

I've been facing similar problems - but not that much (1min+). Generally IIS take some seconds (10~20 sec) to initilize, so manipulating recycle interval (default 1740 min) and idle timeout (default 20 min) may improve your service.